# Deleting LinkedList Last Item

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm writing a program and part of this program is a function that has to delete the last element in a LinkedList:

```
struct node *del_the_last(struct node *head) {
struct node *h1 = head;
if (head == NULL) { 
    return NULL; 
}
while (head->next != NULL) {
    head = head->next;
}
free(h1); 
return head;
}
```

Given the values:

> 16, 7, 8, 12, 13, 19, 21, 12

my program returns

> [12]

however it is supposed to delete it. So I tried again, and this is the closest I got:

```
struct node *del_the_last(struct node *head) {
    struct node *h1 = head;
    int flag = 1;
    if (head == NULL) { return NULL; }
    while (flag == 1) {
        if (head->next->next == NULL) {
            flag = 0;
            head->next = NULL;
            free(h1);
            return head;

        }
        else {
            head = head->next;
        }

    }

}
```

Given the output:

> 2,7,1,8

My program returns:

> 1

Also, I confirmed that the value:

> 8

Is deleted from the LinkedList by trying to return head->next which returned an error

I know how I'd go on about solving this problem, but I'm not sure how to translate that into C code.

This is what my program needs to do:

1. Store the pointer to the head of the node (*head) into a variable
2. Let program run as per normal i.e. the code above
3. Assign head to the value of the pointer in step #1
4. free pointer
5. Return head

I believe this is what needs to be done, but I am not sure how to go about doing them

Kindly advise me the correct way

Comment: what if `head->next` is NULL then `head->next->next` will create problem, isn't it ?

Comment: @achal yeah that's a problem I'll try and fix after I solve the problem above. Sometimes when I run tests I get that line bringing an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @achal, it can be problematic if `head->next` is `NULL` when doing `head->next->next`.

```
struct node* del_the_last(struct node* head){
    struct node* curr = head;
    // Check if head is NULL
    if(head == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    // Special case if head is the only node in the list
    if(head->next == NULL){
        free(head);
        return NULL;
    }
    while(curr != NULL){
        /* Check if curr->next is not NULL. If it's not, 
           see if curr->next->next is NULL, if so, then you 
           know that curr->next is the last node.
        */ 
        if(curr->next != NULL && curr->next->next == NULL){
            free(curr->next);
            /* Important to NULL the link to the delete node 
               so as to signify that now curr->next is the last node
            */ 
            curr->next = NULL; 
        }else{
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample modified code of yours. I tried to explain in comments.

```
struct node *del_the_last(struct node *head) {
        struct node *h1 = head,*temp = NULL;
        if(h1 != NULL) { /* first check head node is NULL or not */
                if(h1->next != NULL) { /* then check head->next */ 
                        while(h1->next->next != NULL) {         
                                h1 = h1->next; /* h1 holds previous of last node when while loop terminates */
                        }
                        temp = h1->next; /*to free last node, assign h1->next to temp */        
                        h1->next = h1->next->next; /* update the previos of last node */
                        free(temp);
                        temp = NULL;
                        return head;

                }
                else { /* if there is only one node in the linked list */
                        head = h1->next; /* make head as NULL */
                        free(h1); /* free temp ptr */
                        h1 = NULL; /* assign it to zero,to avoid memory leakage */
                        return head;
                }

        }
}
```